# Please explain why firstWhere with a malformed orElse expression results in a weird/unexpected result?

Tags: dart

Consider this piece of code:

```dart
  [1, 2, 3].firstWhere(
    (n) => n > 3,
    orElse: () => throw StateError('No match'),
  );
```

This fails, as expected, with an error:

```dart
Bad state: No matchError: Bad state: No match
```

---

But if I change the `orElse` and the `test` condition:

```dart
 [1, 2, 3].firstWhere(
    (n) => n > 1,
    orElse: throw StateError('No match'),
  );
}
```

So:

- Yes, I have made a mistake: `orElse` should be a function.
- But I don't get any syntax errors. And the result is the same error (and not `2`).
- Dart *warns* (not a compilation error, which is why I missed it at first) that the `test` condition is dead code.

---

I realized the mistake and changed the `orElse` to a function, but I am puzzled about the behavior.

Can you help me understand why changing the `orElse` from a function:

```dart
orElse: () => throw StateError('No match')
```

... to an expression:

```
orElse: throw StateError('No match')
```

... results in the `test` condition becoming dead code (but no compilation errors are thrown)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an expression:

```dart
list.firstWhere(condition, orElse: throw StateError('No match'));
```

There is no syntax error because it is legal syntax; `throw StateError('No match')` is a valid Dart expression.  That is what allows:

```dart
void alwaysThrow() => throw Exception();
```

to be valid.

Now, `orElse` expects a `Function`, and `throw StateError('No match')` doesn't return a `Function`, so you might expect a `TypeError` at compilation time.  However, `throw StateError('No match')` doesn't *return* anything.  Dart is an [*applicative-order*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Applicative_order) language; that is, arguments to a function are evaluated before the function (in this case, `firstWhere`) is invoked. `throw StateError(...)` is evaluated *immediately*, and therefore the entire `list.firstWhere(...)` expression is known to unconditionally throw an exception.  Therefore `condition` is irrelevant and is dead code.

Comment: I was about to answer but this is such a great explanation! I just want to add that the usage of `orElse` in this context puzzles me. `firstWhere` is meant to throw a `StateError` by itself if you _don't_ provide it a 'orElse` function!

Comment: @venir - I wanted to throw an exception with a custom message (by default, `firstWhere` throws just a `Bad Element` kind of error). I simplified the error and details to post this question, making it seem weird (now I see) :)

Comment: Oh I see! You also could `try-catch` that btw